# POSTGRES - Should I perfom Indexing on multiple columns or single column

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, postgresql-9.5

I have a relation where I'll be querying the table with two columns for eg: findByXIdAndStatus.

```
select * from X where XId = '12345' and status = 'INACTIVE'
```

Status is a column which holds two values, ACTIVE or INACTIVE. Is it sufficient to create an index on XId column or do I need to create a composite index on both XId and Status or should I create multiple indexes on both columns. Currently I am using postgres DB.

Comment: Since you are asking for *performance*: upgrading to a current version of Postgres should also help. Postgres 9.5 has reached EOL last year. https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 1):

The most performant index might cover the entire `WHERE` clause, and so would be on `(XId, status)`.  However, if the `XId` column itself already be very restrictive, then Postgres might use a single column index on just `XId`.  In that case, Postgres would have to seek back to clustered index to find the `status` value, in order to complete filtering.  In any case, you may try both types of indices, check the `EXPLAIN` plans, and then decide which option to use.

Comment: Postgres doesn't have a clustered index

Answer (score 1):

The single-column index on `xid` is probably good enough.

If only a small percentage of the rows are inactive, a partial index would be beneficial:

```
CREATE INDEX ON x (xid) WHERE status = 'INACTIVE';
```